Not able to fetch models in CRM Analytics Template
I have an app which contains datasets, lenses, dashboards and models. One of the datasets contains discovery predict component which uses a model that is stored under same app.
Template has been created but while fetching the wave template bundle through SF CLI, everything is getting fetched except model.
I am not sure if this will cause any problem when I deploy my app to some other org.
Came across this article - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.250.0.bi_dev_guide_wave_templates.meta/bi_dev_guide_wave_templates/bi_templatesdev_add_discovery_story.htm , it explains adding manually in template-info.json file but the file which they have referred in their example acquired-accounts-story2.json , I am not able to find such file in my local system after retrieving from org.
Any help for the above query would be really appreciated !

When you are working with Salesforce Wave Analytics and deploying assets like datasets, lenses, dashboards, and models across different orgs, it is essential to ensure that all components are included in your deployment package. If the model associated with your discovery predict component is not being fetched, this could lead to issues when you deploy your app to another org. The missing model might cause the discovery predict component to fail, as it won't have the necessary model to reference.I believe you are using:
sfdx force:analytics:template:create -n MyTemplate -d ./outputdir -u myOrgAlias this command to fetch template bundle.
There is one more approach to fetch Wave Analytics components and it's dependencies.

Create a unmanaged package in the org which has the Analytics you are working on.
Add the Dashboard to the package and it will fetch all it's dependencies.
From the cli fetch that package using the following command:
sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "Package_Name".
Align it with the folder structure as it will fetch it as a separate folder and deploy it to the target org.


I am able to get the story json file using above approach and added inside discovery folder of my waveTemplateBundle.
Reason of doing above - my dataset is being generated from a recipe that contains a discovery predict component.
Now my recipe is failing with this error -  [root cause: 404: Einstein Discovery Prediction Definition testanalytics__Predicted_Annual_Revenue_3 not found. ]
I have added the prediction definition file and the model file under same discovery folder but no luck so far.
Not getting a clue where to place the prediction definition file and the model.
